# Host name does not match the certificate subject

Tags: android, ssl, amazon-s3, android-gradle-plugin

I get this gradle error when I try to build my android project.I am using cwac-cam library.

*Error:Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)*

When I tried to open the URL from build.gradle using chrome

> maven { url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com" }

I got this message :

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com (for example, passwords,
>   messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

UPDATE

I tried to open the URL on another device and it opened with no problems.

Comment: If it opened on another device, the other device is incorrect -- you can't use dots in a bucket name *and* use HTTPS with S3 urls of this style.  There is a workaround, but the specifics depend on the region where your bucket is located.  What region is it in?

Comment: Sorry @Michael-sqlbot , but I don't know the region of the bucket, and I don't think this is the problem cause the app was running with this URL earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I get this gradle error when I try to build my android project.I am using cwac-cam library.

There is no `cwac-cam` library that I know of.

The CWAC repository is at:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}
```

which is a slightly different URL than what you have.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. I don't know where that URL came from :)

Comment: Yep, that's the workaround URL format for the us-east-1 (Northern Virginia, formerly called "US Standard") region of S3.

Comment: @MohamedShanan: "I don't know where that URL came from :)" -- that URL used to work, before something changed in Amazon S3. However, that change occurred a year ago or so, and (AFAIK) I updated all my CWAC repositories' documentation to show the correct URL. Perhaps you copied it from a blog post or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I got it, I copied it from an old project. Thanks for help.