# Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android

This is the error I'm getting when I try to build my project, Please help me to solves this I'm stuck at this and I'm a beginner in android.

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

I'm also attaching my app level and build level gradle files.

**App level buld.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories { maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } }
    dependencies { classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.3' }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories { maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } }
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 102
        versionName "1.0.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
//        resConfigs "en"
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app "code",
                                // Live
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

////
//        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "b35433d4-be61-473f-94f8-65364b2cd501",
//                                // Internal Testing
//                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    android {
        buildTypes {
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
                // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
                // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
                // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
                exclude 'META-INF/notice'
                exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/license'
                exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            release {
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-file.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
    }
}
repositories
        {
            maven { url 'https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' }
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
        }
//configurations.all {
//    resolutionStrategy {
//        force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
////        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
//        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
//    }
//}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
//    implementation 'com.helpshift:android-aar:3.7.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.6.1-with-src.jar')
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation files('libs/Parse-1.8.0.jar')
    implementation project(':gallery')
    implementation project(':indicator')
    implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
//    implementation 'com.hokolinks:hoko:2.3.0'
    implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jaydeepw:poly-picker:v1.0.22'
    implementation 'com.github.Commit451:NativeStackBlur:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.Hitta:RippleEffect:82cf00e551'
    implementation 'com.github.zplesac:android_connectionbuddy:v1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.tony19:timber-loggly:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.neumob:neumob-android:3.7.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.10'
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation project(':commonwidget')
    implementation project(':videowidget')
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf.nano:protobuf-javanano:3.0.0-alpha-7'
    implementation project(':Spotlight-library')
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1@aar'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    implementation 'com.pitt.fresh.library:freshdownloadview:1.0'
    implementation 'es.voghdev.pdfviewpager:library:1.0.1'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.11@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
//    implementation 'com.bugsee:bugsee-android:+'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.18.1'
    implementation project(path: ':androidQuery')
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:4.11.0'
    implementation ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
        exclude module: 'answers-shim'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

**Project level buld.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN0yX.png)

**error**

Host name 'repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com, O=Amazon.com Inc., L=Seattle, ST=Washington, C=US)

Comment: Can you attach screen shot of error, because its just a warning message & code compiles/runs well even having this warning message.

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: I think adding google() in your allproject -> repository can solve your problem

Comment: Please check my updated question, now this is the error.

Comment: use either of google() 0r maven { ... }

Comment: May be https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059374/5672138 may help

Answer (score 1):

Hi please replace or update your play service version with the bellow, It will remove the warning

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Comment: Please check my updated question, now this is the error.

Comment: I know, But in my gradel I am getting the same warning like getting you bow, After referring some question on StackOverflow I fond solution which I suggested to you, It was working at me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error it's an warning. Simply for now don't bother.
Change this part like this :

BEFORE:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

AFTER:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need mavenCentral here

Comment: Please check my updated question, now this is the error.